# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(n-1)^n}{n^{n+1}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(n-1)^n}{n^{n+1}}}$$I have tried root test, but it gave me 1 only. What can be done?

Comment: by the comparison test is  this sum divergent

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(k-1)%5Ek%2F(k%5E(k%2B1))),+k%3D1..infinity

Answer (score 6):

It diverges, because $\frac{(n-1)^n}{n^n}=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\overset{n\uparrow\infty}{\longrightarrow} 1/e$, thus there is an $N>0$ such that $\frac{(n-1)^n}{n^n}≥\frac{1}{2e}$ whenever $n≥N$. Therefore $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)^n}{n^{n+1}}$ diverges by comparison with $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2en}$.